# Fingerprint recognition for apple's OS, aka Macs

Tags: macos, image-recognition, fingerprint, biometrics

I'm looking for fingerprint recognition to implement with Java for mac OS's, but everything I find is for Linux and/or Windows. I've searched around on google, but it either does not explicitly state it or it says Windows only. Does anyone have any suggestions or leads as to where I could find this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is just one company who supports it:

http://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?group=platforms_linux_mac

I am sure there are others.